# The job failed. The Job was invoked by Schedule 1012

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup, sql-server-agent

I am new on maintaining database backups, i have problem on my scheduled transaction logs, it was working before until i encountered the error below.

Message:

`The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 1012 (DATABASE01-Trans1PM.Subplan_1).  The last step to run was step 1 (Subplan_1).`

The job was supposed to run at exactly 1pm daily, it is working before until i noticed that it's been 6 days since the same error occurs and the backup job was not successful.

Anyone have an idea on that kind of error message ?

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Comment: Can you check and post the error message of the job step?

Comment: @StijnWynants When i check the history on the server, that is the only error message that is why it's hard for me to troubleshoot.

Comment: Is there anything in your errorlog?

Comment: Here is the event log on server:
DATABASE01-Trans1PM.Subplan_1 
   0xAC8F7C6D2BFC5444AC7F8C12CB90B894 
   Failed 
   2017-02-14 13:00:00 
   The job failed. The Job was invoked by Schedule 1012 DATABASE01-Trans1PM.Subplan_1). The last step to run was step 1 (Subplan_1).

Comment: I mean the errorlog of your SQL Server check for any message at 2017-02-14 13:00:00

Comment: @StijnWynants, on SQL Server Log File viewer, i right clicked the job plan, an view it's history to see the error log.. the message on my orig question was the only message display: `The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 1012 (DATABASE01-Trans1PM.Subplan_1).  The last step to run was step 1 (Subplan_1).`

That is why it's hard for me to troubleshoot it. No other error message, so decided to post in here in stackoverflow.

Comment: So there is no information on both the SQL SERVER ERRORLOG & the SQL SERVER AGENT LOG ?  This is for your database backups? I would suggest you try to use the Ola Hallengren solution. This is a very good backupsolution and is free to use

Comment: Yes, iside from the message on my original question, thanks i'll check your suggestion. Regards

Comment: Hey @ScottHodgin you are an angel! , i forgot i have changed my recovery option to SIMPLE recovery method a week ago because i perform manual backup for some urgent purposes, and i forget to set it back to Full recovery model, and i dont have idea that SIMPLE recovery model cannot do transaction logs backup, you are great! , can you put your comment to answer, and i will mark it as answer, also it can help future readers that will encounter the same issue. Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you indicated your 'transaction log' backup maintenance plan had been working, but was now failing, double check to make sure none of the databases involved in the maintenance plan have somehow gotten changed to `SIMPLE` recovery - transaction logs cannot be backed up in `SIMPLE` recovery mode.

Run this query to identify the recovery mode of all of your databaes.

`select name,recovery_model_desc from sys.databases`

To begin taking transaction log backups again, you'll need to re-establish the log chain by taking at least a `DIFFERENTIAL` backup (although, to keep things nice and clean, I'd recommend a new `FULL` backup) to bridge the gap between the time the database was changed to `SIMPLE` and now.

For more information about the transaction log and `SIMPLE` recovery, please check out these links:

[Backup Under the Simple Recovery Model](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191164(v=sql.105).aspx)

[Transaction Log Truncation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189085(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much @Scott, this solves my problem you're great! :)